# Prove that $E \circ E=E$ (the composition of two equivalence relations is an equivalence relation)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

I am trying to figure out how to show $E \circ E=E$ (the composition of two equivalence relations is an equivalence relation). I have already shown that $a(E \circ E)b \implies aEb$ and need to figure out how to show that  $aEb \implies a(E \circ E)b$. I know that I need to show what allows me to go from $aEb$ to $\exists z\ (aEz \land zEb)$ but I'm not sure how to get there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Hint: use the symmetry of $E$.

Comment: If we are dealing with two different equivalence relations, it would be best to denote them through different symbols. Additionally, what does it mean to *compose* two equivalence relations? An equivalence relation over some set can be seen as a partition of such set (into equivalence classes), so, in equivalent terms, what does it mean *to compose* two partitions?

Comment: This is just how the problem was given to me. The composition of the equivalence relations is as follows: aʎxʎy∃z(xEz^zEy)b

Comment: is that a backwards lambda ???

Comment: I believe what Maria wrote is the same as the following - maybe she can confirm?  $a (R\circ S) b$ iff there is a $c$ for which $a R c$ and $cS b$.  (I believe this not because I can parse the lambda calculus stuff, but because I vaguely recall seeing the definition of composition of relations a long time ago)

Comment: In any situation like this with variables, it makes sense to try obvious choices. In this example, you have $a$ and $b$ already so for $z$ try using one of them.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm obviously not 100% on using symbols on this platform.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: that is the most reasonable interpretation, but we still have to clarify if in Maria's question $E$ simultaneously stands for $R,S$ and $R\circ S$ or not.

Comment: @JasonDeVito that is the same!

Comment: I just noticed that proving "the composition of two equivalence relations is an equivalence relation" is very very different than proving "$E \circ E = E$". Also, one is true and the other is false.

Comment: @mercio can you explain how they are different? My prof gave me the problem. Am I simply reading it incorrectly?

Comment: also @mercio 'E' stands for any equivalence relation in this problem

Answer (score 1):

Assume $aEb$.  Thus $aEa$ anb $aEb$, whence $a E\circ E b$.